# How to find conference papers which do not appear to have been published in any proceeding?

Tags: research-process, proceedings

This question specifically arose from the following situation.

Recently, I have seen several citations referring to papers presented in conferences of the international network on personal relationships (INPR). However, I have been unable to find any proceedings of these conferences. Thus, I am unable to follow up on these citations.

It appears that the INPR no longer exists and has merged with another organisation to form the International Association for Relationship Research (IARR). However, looking at the website of the IARR, no conference proceedings from the conferences of the INPR seem to exist. Neither, does google nor my libraries search function yield any proceedings.

The above situation is quite specific. So I reckon a more general form of this question would be more helpful in the case of this situation reoccurring in the future: how to find articles from conferences which do not appear to have published any proceedings.

Comment: Contact IARR and ask. Contact any author of any of the papers and ask if they are published.

Comment: @Anyon I think that is a good lead, but I do feel like these are distinct cases as I wonder whether these papers have actually been published anywhere. It seems like that question is more about finding old obscure papers rather finding a paper which is affiliated with an organisation that no longer seems to exist in its original form.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you. I will be pursuing this avenue now.

Comment: @Yadeses I see. I read the question as if you've seen normal written citations to a work, in which case it'd make sense to ask a librarian to help finding it. But if the citations are less formal, perhaps in the "presentation at conference X" style, then I agree that Buffy's suggestions are more applicable.